# NullPointerException when I select Items on Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have two spinners, one with a list of countries(countrySpinner) and the other with a list of provinces(stateSpinner). I want the stateSpinner to be active only if Nigeria is selected on the countrySpinner, and for the other countries on to be selectable without selecting item on the stateSpinner. My code seam to work when I select Nigerian on the countrySpinner and a corresponding state, but I GET THIS NullPointerException : println needs a message, anytime I select a country other than Nigeria on the countrySpinner. Not quite sure of what to do to get pass here. I Would appreciate any help. My code below.`enter code here`

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner countrySpinner, stateSpinner;
    List<String> countryList;
    ArrayList<String> stateList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> stateAdapter;
    String countrySelected, stateSelected, gender;
    TextInputLayout name, email, password, confirmPw;
    RadioGroup genderOptionGroup;
    RadioButton genderOptionBtn;
    TextView countryUnCheckedWarning;
    Button nextButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);nextButton = findViewById(R.id.createAccNext);

        countryUnCheckedWarning = findViewById(R.id.countrySelectW);

        genderOptionGroup = findViewById(R.id.gender_group);

        name = findViewById(R.id.fullNameInputLayout);
        email = findViewById(R.id.emailInputLayout);
        password = findViewById(R.id.pwInputLayout);
        confirmPw = findViewById(R.id.cpwInputLayout);

        countrySpinner = findViewById(R.id.countryDropDown);
        stateSpinner = findViewById(R.id.stateDropDown);

        stateList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Select State of Residence", "Abia", "Abuja", "Adamawa", "Akwa Ibom", "Anambra",
                "Bauchi", "Bayelsa", "Benue", "Borno", "Cross River", "Delta", "Ebonyi", "Enugu", "Edo",
                "Ekiti", "Gombe", "Imo", "Jigawa", "Kaduna", "Kano", "Katsina", "Kebbi", "Kogi", "Kwara",
                "Lagos", "Nasarawa", "Niger", "Ogun", "Ondo", "Osun", "Oyo", "Plateau", "Rivers", "Sokoto",
                "Taraba", "Yobe", "Zamfara", "Territory"));

        stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stateList);
        stateAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        stateSpinner.setAdapter(stateAdapter);

        countryList = new ArrayList<String>();

        countryList.add(0, "Select Country");
        countryList.add("Gambia");
        countryList.add("Sierra Leone");
        countryList.add("Liberia");
        countryList.add("Ghana");
        countryList.add("Nigeria");
        countryList.add("South Africa");

        ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countryList);
        countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);

        // Country Spinner

        countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    if (!(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Nigeria")) && !(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Select Country"))){
                        // Country other than Nigeria has been selected
                        countrySelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Log.i("Country Selected is",countrySelected);
                        nextButton.setEnabled(true);
                        nextButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

                    }else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Nigeria")){
                        // Nigeria is selected
                        stateSpinner.setAlpha(1);
                        countrySelected = "Nigeria";
                        nextButton.setEnabled(false);
                        nextButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.silverash));

                    }else {

                        countrySelected = "";
                        nextButton.setEnabled(false);
                        nextButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.silverash));
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        // State SpinnerGroup

        stateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Select State of Residence")) {
                    nextButton.setEnabled(false);
nextButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.silverash));

                } else {

                    stateSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    nextButton.setEnabled(true);
                    nextButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    Log.i("State Selected", stateSelected);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }

    // Name, Email and Password Validation MTDs Below

    private boolean validateName() {
        String nameInpute = name.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        // check for non empty field
        if (nameInpute.isEmpty()) {
            name.setError("Name Field Can't be empty");
            return false;

        } else if (nameInpute.length() < 5) {
            name.setError("Name is too short");
            return false;
        } else {
            name.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateEmail() {

        String emailInpute = email.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        // Now we check for non empty field
        if (emailInpute.isEmpty()) {
            email.setError("E-mail Field Can't be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailInpute).matches()) {
            email.setError("Please enter a valid email address");
            return false;
        } else {
            // Remove Error and return true
            email.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validatePassword() {

        String passwordInpute = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        // check for non empty field
        if (passwordInpute.isEmpty()) {
            password.setError("Password Field Can't be empty");
            return false;

        } else if (passwordInpute.length() > 15) {
            password.setError("Password is too long");
            return false;
        } else {
            password.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateCPassword() {

        String passwordInpute = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String confirmPWInpute = confirmPw.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        // check for non empty field
        if (confirmPWInpute.isEmpty()) {
            confirmPw.setError("Password Field Can't be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!confirmPWInpute.equals(passwordInpute)) {
            confirmPw.setError("Password does not match");
            return false;
        } else {
            password.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }


    public void moveToNextOnReg(View view) {
        // check for or validations

        if (!validateName() | !validateEmail() | !validatePassword() | !validateCPassword()) {
            return; }
        // put whatever result needed here
        String fullName = name.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String emailRegistered = email.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String passwordRegistered = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        Log.i("Name", fullName);
        Log.i("E-mail", emailRegistered);
        Log.i("Password", passwordRegistered);
        Log.i("Country", countrySelected);
        Log.i("State", stateSelected);
        Log.i("Sex", gender);

        Intent intentNext = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ToNextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentNext);
    }

    public void backToOnboarding(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OnboardingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void onGenderSelected(View view){
        int radioId = genderOptionGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        genderOptionBtn = findViewById(radioId);
        gender = genderOptionBtn.getText().toString();
        Log.i("Gender Selceted", genderOptionBtn.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to the line where your code breaks. It would also help to post less code than you have.

Comment: My apologies for  doing a full paste, still learning the rope. I am not quite sure where the code breaks, The app keep restarting anytime a submit a country other than Nigeria in the spinner(coutrySpinner).

Comment: That particular `NullPointerException` happens when you pass null to a `Log` method. I'm not sure if I'm following your description correctly, but if you select "Nigeria" and do not select a state, then `stateSelected` is likely null at `Log.i("State", stateSelected);` in your `moveToNextOnReg()` method. It's not necessarily wrong to have that be null, but you just can't log print it like that. You could either do a null check first, or something like `Log.i("State", String.valueOf(stateSelected));` instead, if you do want that log.

Comment: @MikeM. many thanks for this; simple yet explicit. Making the corrections as you suggested solved the problem, plus, I now understand it better because of your explanation. Uruese!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to initialize `nextButton` in `onCreate()`:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);nextButton = findViewById(R.id.createAccNext);

    countryUnCheckedWarning = findViewById(R.id.countrySelectW);

    genderOptionGroup = findViewById(R.id.gender_group);

    name = findViewById(R.id.fullNameInputLayout);
    email = findViewById(R.id.emailInputLayout);
    password = findViewById(R.id.pwInputLayout);
    confirmPw = findViewById(R.id.cpwInputLayout);

    countrySpinner = findViewById(R.id.countryDropDown);
    stateSpinner = findViewById(R.id.stateDropDown);

    //here.....
    nextButton = findViewById(...............);//what ever the id is in xml
```

Comment: Thankyou @Hasan Bou Taam, I just effected the correction still, the problem persist.